# How to manage Deno dependencies in one place

Tags: deno

In Deno it is possible to version the dependencies in the import statement, and there's no `package.json` like with `npm`.

But how to managed it's URLs and versions in a single place?

I will have multiple files and dependencies that will be declared all over my system.

For example:

**dateUtils.ts**

```js
import { parseDate } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.50.0/datetime/mod.ts';

const DEFAULT_MASK = "dd-mm-yyyy";

export function parse(date: string): Date {
    return parseDate(date, DEFAULT_MASK);
};
```

**service.ts**

```js
import { v4 } from "https://deno.land/std/uuid/mod.ts";

export function process(request: any) {
    const { token } = request;
    const isValid = v4.validate(token);

    console.log(`Token validity: ${isValid}`)

};
```

**app.ts**

```js
import { parse } from "./dateUtil.ts";
import * as service from "./service.ts";

const date = parse("20-05-2020");
console.log(date);

const request = {
    token: "408d30e5-1e90-45e3-b299-6520feee6d76"
}
service.process(request)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid typing `https://deno.land/std/uuid/mod.ts` everywhere you can use [import maps](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/import_maps)

```
// import_map.json

{
   "imports": {
      "http/": "https://deno.land/std/http/"
   }
}
```

```js
// server.ts
import { serve } from "http/server.ts";

const body = new TextEncoder().encode("Hello World\n");
for await (const req of serve(":8000")) {
  req.respond({ body });
}
```

```
deno run --importmap=import_map.json --allow-net server.ts
```

**import maps** are currently unstable, but you can use them behind `--unstable` flag.

---

Aside from that it's common to have a `deps.ts` file where you'll re-export all your dependencies.

```js
// deps.ts
export * as path from "https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/path/mod.ts";
// other exports .. from
```

```js
// some other file
import { path } from './deps.ts' // instead of "https://deno.land/std@0.51.0/path/mod.ts"
path.basename('/bar/test.txt');
```

Comment: The deps convention have a big problem when the projects becomes huge. What if you need the same path function from different dependencies? There will be naming collisions and a mess of knowing where come from each function.

Answer (score 6):

In `deno` there is a convention for consolidating imports into `deps.ts`.

```js
export { parseDate } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.50.0/datetime/mod.ts';
export { v4 } from "https://deno.land/std/uuid/mod.ts";
```

Exports can then be imported in other modules/scripts on your application:

```js
import { v4 } from "./deps.ts";
import { parseDate } from './deps.ts';

const myUUID = v4.generate();
parseDate("20-05-2020", "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

When using this approach one should consider [integrity checking & lock files](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/integrity_checking):

```js
// Add a new dependency to "src/deps.ts", used somewhere else.
export { xyz } from "https://unpkg.com/xyz-lib@v0.9.0/lib.ts";
```

```sh
# Create/update the lock file "lock.json".
deno cache --lock=lock.json --lock-write src/deps.ts

# Include it when committing to source control.
git add -u lock.json
git commit -m "feat: Add support for xyz using xyz-lib"
git push
```