# How to keep the version of packages in Deno

Tags: versioning, deno

I don't quite understand how I can keep the version of packages in a `Deno` project.

I saw that it loads packages via urls directly without using `package.json` that I had in Nodejs project.

That's cool but how do I keep the versions of some libraries that I used in the project? My concern is if a library has updated some of its functions and then my server will be broken.

Actually I believe I must miss something that is very common.

Could anyone give me a hint on this question?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but this post might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917605/how-to-manage-deno-dependencies-in-one-place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [versioned imports from deno.land](https://deno.land/x#info) to make sure to always get the version with which you have developed your software. Deno.land caches releases and allow to import by version number.

Instead of writing:

```js
import { validateJwt } from "https://deno.land/x/djwt/validate.ts";
```

which would always import the current version of the package,
you can add the version number as `@<version>` behind the package name to explicitely import that version (here version 1.7):

```js
import { validateJwt } from "https://deno.land/x/djwt@v1.7/validate.ts";
```

To check for updates there's a third party module [deno-check-updates](https://deno.land/x/deno_check_updates@v0.3)
that works with [import maps](https://deno.land/manual/linking_to_external_code/import_maps).
But please be aware that import maps is still marked as an unstable feature and deno-check-updates is also only on v0.3 yet and currently doesn't work due to changes on deno side.

Just tried `deno run -A --unstable https://deno.land/x/deno_check_updates/main.ts -f import_map.json` and got an error.

I'll check and update this answer as soon as I know more.

Comment: hi @jps, thanks for your answer. Is there any other better way to handle the version? If I want to update a package, should i check their repository to get the updated version number?

Comment: wow that's awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

For me, I just put the imports in `deps.ts` or `deps/modname.ts`

ex.:

***deps/abc.ts***

```js
export { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.2.1/mod.ts";
```

***main.ts***

```js
import * as abc from "./deps/abc.ts";
```

Comment: I see this pattern often but are there official source describing this?
I am confused how you would handle tree-shaking (sometimes loading Foo, sometimes Bar from a package?) and also how to avoid having "../../../../deps/foobar.ts", maybe TS paths are enough here?